# FluentAssertions: Assert that a collection contains any item that contains a string (case insensitive)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a collection of strings

```
var greetings = new[] { "Hello boy", "Hello girl", "Hello all"};
```

I would like to create an assertion using *FluentAssertions* that verifies that the collection contains at least one item that contains a given string.

Example. For the previous collection,

- testing with "boy", should pass.
- testing with "Girl" should pass.
- testing with "hello" should pass.
- testing with "ouch" should NOT pass (because there is not item in the collection that contains this string).

I've tried with:

```
greetings.Should().ContainMatch("*" + str + "*");
```

But it doesn't work becuase it's case sensitive.

Comment: `greetings.Where(g => g.Contains(str, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Should().NotBeEmpty();` using the example provided by gunr

Comment: For completeness, there should be a `ContainMatchEquivalentOf` (to mirror `String.MatchEquivalentOf`). Without it `greetings.Should().Contain(s => s.MatchEquivalentOf("*" + str + "*"))` should do it (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sadly, your code doesn't work. The nested MatchEquivalentOf call isn't correct. Prepending "Should()" doesn't help, either.

Comment: `greetings.Should().Contain(x=>x.Contains("Boy", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));`